# How to pass parameter in Angularjs $http.post

Tags: angularjs

Here i'm trying to pass the value of "$scope.getCourse = 'adobe'" to the server so that it returns the corresponding course details, from where i can populate list using ng-repeat from the response data. But the below code fails when i insert "$scope.getCourse" along with servelet url.

```
var courseApp = angular.module('courseApp', []);

courseApp.controller('courseCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    //$scope.getCourse = 'adobe'; //need to pass this value to the server;

    $http.post('javaServerlet', $scope.getCourse).success(function(data){
        $scope.result = data.MainTopic;
        $scope.lessons = data.CourseOutline;
    })  
}])
```

json format from servelet

```
{ 
    "MainTopic": "Adobe",
    "RunningTime": "6h11min",
    "Description": "Course Description comes here",
    "CourseOutline":
    [ 
        { "Lessons" : "Lesson 1" , "Title" : "Introduction1" , "Duration" : "31m 27s"},
        { "Lessons" : "Lesson 2" , "Title" : "Introduction2" , "Duration" : "56m 05s"},

    ]
}
```

Please let me know how to achieve the above senario, I'm very new to angularjs.

Comment: How does the code fail?  Do you get a console error?  Does the success function not run?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your `data` should be a key/val pair, try:

```
$http.post('javaServerlet', {course: $scope.getCourse})
```

And that variable will get to the server under the parameter `course`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot for ur quick response.

Comment: If there are multiple parameters, are they just comma-separated?

Comment: Thank you so much Abhilash , tymeJV